# away3d remove from memory

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, away3d

I am building a website which loads some collada objects for each area.
But I couldn't manage to clean the memory. It seems impossible to kill the objects.

I've found some samples implementing destroy() methods for away3d internal classes, but they're not working as well.

I really don't know if this is a problem with player's garbage collector or with away3d itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is with Away3D and not the garbage collector. I've had a similar issue and after a lot of searching I just had to deal with the memory leak and try to stop it from getting out of hand by recycling the objects/pooling.

You can see that memory leaks are actively discussed on the forums but there hasn't been much in the way of easy fixes: http://groups.google.com/group/away3d-dev/browse_thread/thread/3d31808f4d50f0d2/0ef840a2395f3783?lnk=gst&q=memory#0ef840a2395f3783

Answer (score 1):

Grant Skinner figured out an unsupported way of [Forcing Garbage Collection](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/08/as3_resource_ma_2.html), maybe try that out and see if memory usage decreases?  If not, it's at least not the flash player.

```
try {
   new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
   new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
} catch (e:*) {}
// the GC will perform a full mark/sweep
// on the second call of new LocalConnection().connect().
```

Best,
Lance

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will be very useful. But it stills in memory.